# Upgraded to 14.04 from 13.10 and it made my computer slow

Tags: upgrade, internet

For some reason my computer now got extremely slow. My Internet connection is frequently disconnected and sometimes it just won't work after upgrading from 13.10. I had no problems at all with 13.10, I wish it were the same with 14.04. Is there anything I can do to fix or, at least, diagnose this?

Comment: That is obviously not a feature of Ubuntu, but some kind of technical glitch. Based on the information you provide, it's impossible to even speculate. In the heading, internet is slow. In the text, computer is slow. You should try to provide some information. Otherwise, it'll just be wild guesses, like "your internet provider might have throttled your connection because you've downloaded too much". Millions of possibilities.

Comment: Internet works the same (normal and fast) on my tablet, wife's tablet and Xbox. When I want to use the internet on my comp its slow, keeps connecting and disconnecting, and has a weak signal. When I had 13.10 the internet worked just fine like anything connected to the internet with a good connection.

Comment: Please do what is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: I followed and did the command you posted and not a whole lot changed.

Comment: Try browsing in live Ubuntu session (select Try Ubuntu after booting from USB/DVD) on that system. Does it have the same issues as well? If it does, we can pin down 14.04 as the cause. Otherwise, it's possible it's a hardware problem or something went wrong during the upgrade.

Answer (score -1):

The same problem: all applications, and especially firefox are very slow after upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04. The internet link is normal.
I found the answer here:
http://gaijin-nippon.blogspot.ru/2014/04/baloofileextractor-makes-disk-spinning.html

One has to kill baloo_file_extractor:
$ cp /usr/share/autostart/baloo_file.desktop ~/.kde/share/autostart/
$ echo "Hidden=True" >> ~/.kde/share/autostart/baloo_file.desktop

After logout and login again to kde-plasma session, everything is OK

Comment: I am new to Linux and don't really know Linux talk that well. So if I put that into the terminal, press enter, log out and log in again it should work? I am also using Google chrome.

Comment: This helped a bit for me. I don't know if the problem it totally fixed yet. I'll have to see after I restart.